# Como mostrar Sequências de escape como String em C#?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho um método em C# que recebe uma String e às vezes possui escapes de saída dentro, como `\n`. Ele faz sua função normalmente, que é pular a linha. **Porém quero que eles sejam mostrados como String**.

**Como posso fazer isso?**

Tentei remover os escapes com `String.Remove` e adicionar `\\n` na mesma posição com `String.Insert`, para que ele imprisse uma String mostrando o escape, mas não obtive êxito.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    String name = "N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
  }
}

/* 
Saída:
"N ffns bt,
Yr wrtng" 
*/
```

**Saída que quero obter:**

```
"N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng"
```

Comment: Editei, quero sejam mostrados os escapes quando eu, por exemplo, executar `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(name.Replace("\n", "\\n"))`??? é isso

Comment: `string name = @"N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng"` o `@` vai armazenar a string de forma literal... o seu problema é exatamente esse ou recebendo de outra variável?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, dá pra usar no return? Estou recebendo de outra variável e retornando.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, Isso dá certo até o momento de eu retornar isso de uma função, porque aí o resultado da função é `N ffns bt,\\nYr wrtng`, com duas barras

Comment: @EduardoNogueira *"Isso dá certo até o momento de eu retornar isso de uma função"* mais é uma coisa que vc precisa resolver :)  segundo o seu exemplo, o `Replace` funciona perfeitamente, agora se é um caso diferente da pergunta,  precisa editar a pergunta então ou adaptar a solução

Answer (score 0):

```
string stg = @"N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng";
Console.WriteLine(stg);
```

Saída no console:

```
> N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng
```

Usando "@" ele ignora os escapes da string